# ajax post and redirect to new page not work

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I use `resource` make crud, and in the `create` page, I have to add a preview page

I tried to use ajax post data to `admin/article/previewform` then in route action controller method `previewform` catch data and store in variable with redirect to new page `preview` show it ...
I have problem
1. Why it doesn't redirect to new page ?
2. Why in js console.log get `Faild to load resource … statu?s of 500`
3. I also try `return Redirect::to('admin/article/previewshow');` in `previewform` then still not redirect to.
But get js console.log  with template `show.blade.php`that is in `resource` `show` method call.. ??

How to solve it?

js

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'previewform',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {data: data},
})
.done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

route

```
//.. prefix=>admin
Route::resource('article','AdminArticleController');

Route::post('admin/article/previewform', 'AdminArticlePreviewController@previewform');
Route::get('admin/article/preview', 'AdminArticlePreviewController@preview');
```

AdminArticlePreviewController

```
class AdminArticlePreviewController extends AdminController
{
    public function preview()
{
    $input = Input::get('data');

    return Redirect::route('admin/article/previewshow');
}

public function previewshow()
{
    // return View::make('admin.article.preview')->with('data', $data)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to make redirection in this way. For ajax requests you need to catch "redirection command" from the server side script (PHP) and execute it in the JS.

Instead:

`return Redirect::route('admin/article/previewshow');`

you can use:

`return Response::make('/redirect/url', 301)`

then JS code:

`.done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});`

can be replaced by something like:

`.done(function(data, statusText, xhr) {
    if(xhr.status == 301) {
        window.location = data;
    }
});`